# Eclipse import Maven from different folder

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project on disk, its POM is located under `C:/User/MyProject`.

If I try to import this POM into Eclipse, it creates the `.settings` and `.classpath` in the same directory (`C:/User/MyProject`). I don't want this. It is possible to keep the POM directory clean and to put the Eclipse files into another directory, like `C:/Workspace/MyProject`?

I'm using Eclipse 2019.12, Oracle JDK 13 and Maven 3.6.

Comment: Not that I know. Eclipse needs this configuration files. BTW: What is the real problem with them?

Comment: Best practice is not to separate project-specific files (including those mentioned above) but keep them together in the project folder. In Eclipse, a project can contain linked files and folder, but in this case it is not recommended. If you share the project, `.classpath` can be ignored but the `.settings` folder should be shared as it contains project-specific settings that are not covered by the POM file (e.g. compiler warnings, formatter settings, etc.).